# Is the following sentence wrong? "The food I feel winter by seeing one is strawberry."

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

Is the following sentence wrong?

> "The food I feel winter by seeing one is strawberry."

Could you also tell me if the following sentence is natural or not.

> "The food by which I feel winter is strawberry."

Thank you everybody!

I'm sorry that I have trouble expressing my question, but please let me elaborate on my question.

I would like to mean the following sentence starting by the word "The food" if possible.

"When I see strawberry (in a supermarket), I feel that winter has come."

"Strawberries remind me of winter." sounds nice, but I feel that it might have a slight difference from what I want to explain. 
(Am I wrong?)

By the way, if it sounds strange because of "winter", please change it to "summer".

That part was not important, and I think I should have written "summer" instead.

Comment: The first sentence is a word salad, not a sentence. The second is grammatical but rather strange-sounding.

Comment: Are you trying to say that *the strawberry is a typical winter food?*  Aside from the syntax, I'm curious why that would be true.  I've always known **summer** to be strawberry season.

Comment: I SLIGHTLY disagree with robusto. The first sentence iis ungrammatical and so has no discernible meaning.  Accepting the obvious truth that nonsense can be grammatical, the second sentence may be grammatical, but it is complete nonsense rather than merely strange-sounding.

Comment: Dear Jeff, "it is complete nonsense" is because it says "winter" instead of "summer", or else?

Comment: Do you live in the southern hemisphere? Because strawberries in Italy is usually associated with **mid-spring** and **early summer**. In the UK summer is when strawberries are in full **season**. http://www.seriouseats.com/2010/05/in-season-strawberries-choosing-storing-recipes-20100515.html

Comment: Dear Mari-Lou,   I live in the north hemisphere.  However, rather a lot strawberries start to sell in a supermarket around us.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of those sentences is idiomatic English. I don't fully understand what idea you're trying to convey, but your sentence would probably be clearer if you used **"Strawberry"** as the subject. If you rearrange the sentence that way, you can also drop **"the food by"** to be more concise.

**"Feel winter"** is also not common English. You can feel cold, but that doesn't seem to make sense in context. If you mean that strawberries make you think of winter, try saying:

> "Strawberries remind me of winter."

or

> Strawberries make me think of winter."

Comment: I agree that "Strawberries remind me of winter" is grammatical. Is it sane?